# Share code between Gradle buildSrc and project

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Suppose I have some classes containing logic that I would like to use during the Gradle build and in the Java application itself. How can configure a Gradle build to share the same classes between a build and the project that is being built, for example using the Kotlin DSL?

Comment: It's interesting whether the same is possible to be achieved with Gradle modules instead of pointing to source sets directly. Gradle modules should make it more reusable, encapsulated and performant. But the only way I see for this currently is introduction of local Maven repositories having its own downsides.

Comment: Update to the comment above - seems like such Gradle module-based approach can be implemented by using `includeBuild(...)`. While such way can't be treated as something very new, the key point here is to make sure no conflicts or other issues will appear in cases of build script's and actual project's interoperability (for example, when both project and some build script module depend on the same third module).

Answer (score 4):

You can just add the shared classes in `buildSrc` to your application classpath like so:

```gradle
sourceSets["main"].compileClasspath += files("${project.rootDir}/buildSrc/build/")
```

As @lance-java mentions, you should also add a compile dependency:

```
dependencies {
  compile(fileTree("${project.rootDir}/buildSrc/build/"))
}
```

Finally, if a class you need to use imports from `org.gradle.api`, add this line to `dependencies`:

```
compile(gradleApi())
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @breandan's answer, I think it's better as:

```gradle
apply plugin: 'java' 
dependencies {
    compile files("${project.rootDir}/buildSrc/build/classes/" )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the provided answers which describe how to include shared classes just by pointing to them directly, I want to show how to solve the same problem in a modular way. By using Gradle modules ([composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)) it's possible to get at least the following benefits:

1. Better modularity and reusability: shared classes are kept in a separate Gradle module which can be stored and updated independently (for example, in another Git repository).
2. Stricter encapsulation: it's possible to leverage features of the `internal` visibility modifier in Kotlin, no need to know where the sources to be shared are located, no need to include resources manually in a `sourceSets`-like manner.
3. Improved performance: no need to compile shared classes for each place they are going to be used in.
4. Simplicity in switching between locally compiled and published artifacts for shared classes: see [the corresponding Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#deactivate_included_build_substitutions).

**How to do such configuration?**

1. Create 3 projects: **main** - for the main application, **dsl** - for build scripts, **shared** - for shared classes. It's possible to use an IDE's wizard, just make sure each of created projects is self-sufficient (having its own `settings.gradle.kts`).
2. Make sure **shared** has some `group`, `rootProject.name` and `version` assigned in its `settings.gradle.kts` and `build.gradle.kts` files. These properties are important to be set as we will use them to include this project as a dependency.
3. In `settings.gradle.kts` of **dsl** add:

   ```kotlin
   includeBuild("../shared") // points to the root directory of the shared project
   ```

   In the same **dsl** project create and declare some plugin which is going to do your build script work. Inside `dsl/src/main/kotlin/` create:

   ```kotlin
   class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

       override fun apply(target: Project) {
           // Required build script configurations for the project.
       }

   }
   ```

   Inside **dsl**'s `build.gradle.kts` add:

   ```kotlin
   plugins {
       // ...
       `java-gradle-plugin`
   }

   gradlePlugin {
       plugins {
           create("my-plugin") {
               id                  = "my-plugin"
               implementationClass = "MyPlugin"
           }
       }
   }

   // ...

   dependencies {
       // Replace with everything has been configured at the second step.
       implementation("group:projectName:version")
   }
   ```
4. In **main**'s `settings.gradle.kts` add:

   ```kotlin
   includeBuild("../shared")
   includeBuild("../dsl")
   ```

   In **main**'s `build.gradle.kts` add:

   ```kotlin
   plugins {
       // ...
       id("my-plugin")
   }

   // ...

   dependencies {
       // Replace with everything has been configured at the second step.
       implementation("group:projectName:version")
   }
   ```

Congratulations, you've got the sources of **shared** project used both inside your build scripts (**dsl**) and the main app (**main**)!