# Sharing variables between library and application

Tags: android, gradle, buildsrc

What would be the best way to share some values like version code or name between android app and library? I need to be able to use it in the gradle file and kotlin files (like when using BuildConfig file). I was trying with buildSrc and sharing files like described here: [Share code between Gradle buildSrc and project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219106/share-code-between-gradle-buildsrc-and-project) but I wasn't able to add anything to `compileClasspath` because as I can see this value is in Gradle SourceSet https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet:compileClasspath and it's not available in AndroidSourceSet which is used in `sourceSets`.

Comment: Have you tried [versions catalog](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs)?

Comment: I need to be able to use it also in kotlin files like activities or fragments

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of sharing values between a Gradle build file and the target program is to use the [Gradle BuildConfig plugin](https://github.com/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin)

Here you can write the following in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig") version "5.3.5"
}

buildConfig {
    buildConfigField("APP_NAME", project.name)
    buildConfigField("APP_VERSION", provider { "\"${project.version}\"" })
}
```

And it will generate an object of constants in your project for you to access:

```
internal object BuildConfig {
    internal const val APP_NAME: String = "kts"
    internal const val APP_VERSION: String = "\"0.1.0-demo\""
}
```